# Recursive Function Error: "-var-create: unable to create variable object"

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, vscode-debugger

I made a Binary Tree for storing 2 chars 'R' and 'B'. The inserting and printing functions work fine but while executing searching function, the pointer variable gives the error `-var-create: unable to create variable object` when watched under VS code's debugger tool.

Node Struct Code:

```
struct Node
{
    Node * left;
    Node * right;
    char value;
    bool endSeq = false;
};
```

BST's Search Functions:

```
bool search(string k)
        {
            int len = k.length();
            bool found = false;
            searchHelper(root, k, len, found);
            if(found)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

Node * searchHelper(Node * p, string k, int & len, bool & found)
        {
            if(p == NULL)
            {
                return NULL;
            }
            else if(len == 0)
            {
                if(p->endSeq)
                {
                    found = true;       
                }
                return p;
            }
            else if(k[0] < p->value || (k[0] == 'B' && k[0] == p->value))
            {
                string kNew = k.substr(1, --len);
                if(p->endSeq)
                {
                    found = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    insertHelper(p->left, kNew, len);
                }
            }
            else if(k[0] > p->value || (k[0] == 'R' && k[0] == p->value))
            {
                string kNew = k.substr(1, --len);
                if(p->endSeq)
                {
                    found = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    insertHelper(p->right, kNew, len);   
                }
            }
            return p;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a problem in your code. You have made a wrong recursive call. Instead of calling insertHelper you should call searchHelper